# How to integrate extent reports with jenkins.?

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

Please help to integrate Extent reports with Jenkins.  Have implemented extent reports in selenium webdriver, trying to integrate with Jenkins.

Comment: nothing to integrate with jenkins, if jenkins run your selenium project, than extent report will generate a report by default. but if you want to do something with that report, u have to keep it in your jenkins workspace.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to send email with extentReport in it. If You like this than You can use this plugin bellow:
[https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin]

and as editable mail notification inject Extent-report that You've already generated and stored inside Your code. Just link it.

Another way, if You/Your company can provide is to follow steps from this link

[https://github.com/anshooarora/klov]

and start Klov server which is basically extension of Extent-reports library, which is basically an server who connects to mongoDB and store Your results and history and have maybe more benefit than Jenkins reporting, anyone can access it at any time, and has all results user should need without searching in emails.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is a source automation server, Jenkins provides hundreds of plugins to support building, deploying and automating any project.If your project have extent report in it then it will just run your build and it will generate your report.